# Maps and text in css

Tags: html, css, mapbox

I am new to CSS but have a relatively simple goal. My objective is to format a webpage to display a series of maps with text in between.  In the end, the layout will be as follows with the page scrollable:

```
text
map
text
map
text
map
```

Both text and maps should be centered.  In order to place the maps in the center of the page, I attach each `map` to the `map-container` but I am not sure that this is the right method.  The following markdown overlaps the maps, and does not allow one to scroll down the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title></title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.38.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/turf/v3.0.11/turf.min.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.38.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body { margin:0; padding:0; }
        #map { 
          position:absolute; 
          top:50%; bottom:0; 
          width:100%;
          height:50%; 
          overflow: auto;}

        #map2 { 
          position:fixed; 
          top:75%; 
          bottom:0; 
          width:100%; 
          height:50%; 
          overflow: auto;}

        #map-container {
          overflow: scroll;
          position: absolute;
          height: 500px;
          width: 500px;
          top: 50%;
          left: 50%;
          transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: -webkit-translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: -moz-translate(-50%, -50%);
          transform: -ms-translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<style>
button {
    position: fixed;
    margin: 5px;
    right: 0px;
    z-index: 1010101010
}

#pause::after {
    content: 'Pause';
}

#pause.pause::after {
    content: 'Play';
}
</style>
<div id='map-container'><div style="position:absolute; color:#282828; font-family:Arial; font-weight:200;"><br><b>TEST  </b></br>
</div>
<div id='map'>
<button id='pause'></button>
</div>
<div id='map2'></div>
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Both maps are children of the same parent element. I have tried changing the position parameter, changing top/bottom although nothing works - either one map covers the other or they overlap. What am I doing wrong ? Any suggestions or basic template on how to put maps in between text would be very helpful.

[image]

Comment: Hello! I would love to assist you with your problem. From looking at your code, I can see that there are a lot of unnecessary css that takes place. Displaying every item as a block element "display: block;" and placing them in a proper place in the html markup, will grant you the result that you desire. Here is a CodePen that I setup: https://codepen.io/CapySloth/pen/NgJwZq.

Comment: Your main culprits for overlaying of maps are the setting of maps with parameters "position:absolute" and "position:fixed". Both are not meant to be "dynamic". To try describe it in a metaphor; They do not care about the existence of each-other, so instead of what you want them to do (sit next to each-other), one will sit on top the other.

Comment: Can map be more then 100% of screen width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this via flexbox. No need for additional containers. Demo:

```css
body {
  /* Make body a flex-container */
  display: flex;
  /* Specify direction where all items will */
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Center all items in this direction */
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
Look how many maps we've got!
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoxkJ.jpg" />
Some text
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/70PBD.jpg" />
This is also text
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8Kaj.jpg" />
Maps are awesome
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also does not work because the maps I am displaying  are not images

Comment: @the_darkside That doesn't matter. You can display them as `div`s with `background-image` with fixed sizes. The main idea is to have `flex-container` with direct children. Does it help you?

Comment: If `position` is not defined, the maps will not display at all.  Can you provide an example with a simple mapbox map?

Comment: @the_darkside Can you please create clear fiddle where I can reproduce your markup?

Comment: @the_darkside Is it possible to rewrite your markup using this method without absolute positioning? If you don't need overlap try avoiding absolute positioning. But even if you need absolute positioning I can't help you without some clear example where I can see some results, not just code.

Comment: This map can be used and reproduced three times in between text for example - though it should not be 100% of the screen - rather only 500px by 500px box in the middle of the screen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149529/discussion-between-the-darkside-and-vadim-ovchinnikov).

Comment: @the_darkside Well, I can't see anything that I would just call text on fiddle. You've posted me all code you've got, not just minimal example to reproduce the issue and it's very hard even to understand your issue, not speaking about to fix it. To center box in the middle of screen is trivial. https://jsfiddle.net/2rs72wus/1/

Comment: @the_darkside I would chat with you, but it's very late my time, I need to go to bed. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and all of your content is in the center

```
<style>
    body { margin:0; padding:0; }
    #map { 
      width:100%;
      height:50%; 
      overflow: auto;}

    #map2 { 
      width:100%; 
      height:50%; 
      overflow: auto;}

    .text{
        color:#282828; font-family:Arial; font-weight:200;
    }
#map-container{
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```
<body>

<div id='map-container'>
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
    <div id='map'></div>
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
    <div id='map2'></div>
    <div class="text">TEXT</div>
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```